# lit-element in typescript. Cannot find module

Tags: typescript, lit-element

I have cloned this repository that uses @babel/preset-typescript instead of ts-loader.

https://github.com/a-tarasyuk/webpack-typescript-babel

Then I added lit-element as a dependency

yarn add lit-element

However, when I import the following

```js
import {LitElement, html, css, customElement, property} from 'lit-element';
```

I get the following error:

`src / index.ts: 5: 62 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'lit-element'.`

I am a beginner, am I forgetting something?

Comment: What happens when you run `./node_modules/.bin/tsc --noemit --project tsconfig.json` from the command line?

Comment: Hi @AluanHaddad, When I do this I get the same error

Comment: Then the error has nothing to do with `@babel/preset-typescript` or any other loader. It is a static typechecking error from the TypeScript language. You need to track it down

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I had this issue, adding: "moduleResolution": "node", to the compilerOptions in the ts.config file worked for me.